# Double Extension Swift

Tags: swift, double

I am trying to create an iOS Swift extension in a playground to the **Double** type that implements a method titled **add** that receives a **String** and returns an optional *Double (Double?)*.

Extend the **Double** type, using an extension, and add a method called **add** that takes a **String** as a parameter with no label and returns a **Double?**.

If the **String** parameter can be turned into a **Double**, return the **String**’s **Double** value plus the value of the **Double** on which add is being called. If the **String** cannot be turned into a **Double**, return nil.

For testing this code I need to use:

```
let value1: Double? = 3.5.add("1.2") //value should be 4.7

let value3: Double? = 1.5.add("words") //value should be nil
```

```
extension Double {
    func add(_ value: String) -> Double? {
        guard let someNum = Double?(self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return (someNum + value)
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLM2E.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got a little confused about what to unwrap in your `guard` statement and what needed to be turned from a `String` into a `Double`. In your current code, you try to turn `self`, which is *already* a `Double` into a `Double?` -- then, you try to add that `Double?` to a `String`.

Here's a fixed version:

```
extension Double {
    func add(_ value: String) -> Double? {
        guard let numValue = Double(value) else {
            return nil
        }
        return self + numValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Following Swift naming conventions I would name this method `adding`. It is not a mutating method.

Comment: Reasonable point. From the OP's wording, though, I assume this is some sort of assignment (which I recognized after I answered) and it looks like the naming is decided for them.

Comment: Yes fair point. Btw you can use the same namespacing `let value = Double(value)`

Comment: Sure, but are there any advantages? To me, it seems more confusing to shadow a variable name for a Swift beginner who is already having trouble figuring out which variable is which.

Comment: The advantage IMO is hiding the old string object which is not needed after converting to Double. But I agree about OP being a beginner and it might be confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I see the logic there.